# inventory of installed apps

Tags: ansible, redhat, devops

I am running the last 4 versions of redhat want a list of what is installed.

I would do a `service --list-all` and then add the stuff I found manually such as java, but redhat 7 does not put out the same kind of list as other redhats.

Is there an ansible service list module that runs the same on all recent redhats?

Outside of ansible, here is one of my attempts to work with redhat 7:

```
ansible all -m raw -a "systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
- raw: yum list installed
  register: inst

- debug: msg=inst
```

Answer (score 0):

`service --list-all` is a syntax error in both RHEL/CentOS 5 and 6, so you're not including the actual code you're using.  Do you mean `service --status-all`, or `chkconfig --list`?  But neither of those gives you an inventory of installed apps, that would be `rpm -qa`, or maybe you mean `yum list all`?

Once you figure out what you're actually trying to get, you could call the command/shell module and register a variable, then iterate through the stdout lines, like:

```
- shell: mycommand
  register: myvar

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ myvar.stdout_lines }}"
```

Otherwise your question whether a module exists can't be answered because what you're asking is different than the examples you have provided.